# Error "Provided document reference is from a different Firestore instance." al hacer un batch en firebase

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, firebase, firestore

Al hacer un batch en firebase que sale este error.

> Provided document reference is from a different Firestore instance.

Este es mi código

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
db = getFirestore(app),
date = new Date();

const batch = writeBatch(db);
      batch.set(addDoc(collection(db, `cities`), {
    city: object.city,
    state: object.state,
    country: object.countries
}))
```

Cuando yo hago este cambio ya no me marca ese error. Lo que pasa es que no quiero estar pasando un ID manualmente

```
batch.set(doc(db, `cities/${idManual}`), {
    city: object.city,
    state: object.state,
    country: object.countries
})
```